# Using WCSession with more than one ViewController

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2

I found many questions and many answers but no final example for the request:

Can anyone give a final example **in Objective C** what is best practice to use WCSession with an IOS app and a Watch app (WatchOS2) with **more than one ViewController**.

What I noticed so far are the following facts:

1.) Activate the WCSession in the parent (IOS) app at the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Any other code you might have

    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        self.session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        self.session.delegate = self;
        [self.session activateSession];
    }
}
```

2.) On the WatchOS2 side use `<WCSessionDelegate>`. But the rest is totally unclear for me! Some answers are talking from specifying keys in the passing Dictionary like:

```
[session updateApplicationContext:@{@"viewController1": @"item1"} error:&error];
[session updateApplicationContext:@{@"viewController2": @"item2"} error:&error];
```

Others are talking about retrieving the default session

```
WCSession* session = [WCSession defaultSession];
[session updateApplicationContext:applicationDict error:nil];
```

Others are talking about different queues? **"It is the client's responsibility to dispatch to another queue if necessary. Dispatch back to the main."**

I am totally confused. So please give an example how to use WCSession with an IOS app and a WatchOS2 App with more than one ViewController.

*I need it for the following case (simplified):
In my parent app I am measuring heart rate, workout time and calories. At the Watch app 1. ViewController I will show the heart rate and the workout time at the 2. ViewController I will show the heart rate, too and the calories burned.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I understand the task you just need synchronisation in a `Phone -> Watch` direction so in a nutshell a minimum configuration for you:

**Phone:**

I believe the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` handler is the best place for the `WCSession` initialisation therefore place the following code there:

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    // You even don't need to set a delegate because you don't need to receive messages from Watch.
    // Everything that you need is just activate a session.
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}
```

Then somewhere in your code that measures a heart rate for example:

```
NSError *updateContextError;
BOOL isContextUpdated = [[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:@{@"heartRate": @"90"} error:&updateContextError]

if (!isContextUpdated) {
    NSLog(@"Update failed with error: %@", updateContextError);
}
```

**update:**

**Watch:**

ExtensionDelegate.h:

```
@import WatchConnectivity;
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>

@interface ExtensionDelegate : NSObject <WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate>
@end
```

ExtensionDelegate.m:

```
#import "ExtensionDelegate.h"

@implementation ExtensionDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    // Session objects are always available on Apple Watch thus there is no use in calling +WCSession.isSupported method.
    [WCSession defaultSession].delegate = self;
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}

- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {
     NSString *heartRate = [applicationContext objectForKey:@"heartRate"];

    // Compose a userInfo to pass it using postNotificationName method.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:heartRate forKey:@"heartRate"];

    // Broadcast data outside.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"heartRateDidUpdate" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}

@end
```

Somewhere in your Controller, let's name it XYZController1.

XYZController1:

```
#import "XYZController1.h"

@implementation XYZController1

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleUpdatedHeartRate:) name:@"heartRateDidUpdate" object:nil];
}

-(void)handleUpdatedHeartRate:(NSNotification *)notification {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSString* heartRate = userInfo[@"heartRate"];
        NSLog (@"Successfully received heartRate notification!");
}

@end
```

Code hasn't been tested I just wrote it as is so there can be some typos.

I think the main idea now is quite clear and a transfer of remaining types of data is not that tough task.

My current WatchConnectivity architecture much more complicated but nevertheless it is based on this logic.

If you still have any questions we might move a further discussion to the chat.

Comment: I will try it! Seems to be very simple! I found here a good post for the NSNotificationCenter I will use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080605/add-addobserver-nsnotificationcenter-in-a-1st-view-controller-handle-in-2n

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is simplified version of my solution as requested by [Greg Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4193439/greg-robertson). Sorry it's not in Objective-C anymore; I'm just copy-pasting from existing AppStore-approved project to make sure there will be no mistakes.

Essentially, any WatchDataProviderDelegate can hook to data provider class as that provides array holder for delegates (instead of one weak var).
Incoming WCSessionData are forwarded to all delegates using the notifyDelegates() method.

```
// MARK: - Data Provider Class

class WatchDataProvider: WCSessionDelegate {

    // This class is singleton
    static let sharedInstance = WatchDataProvider()

    // Sub-Delegates we'll forward to
    var delegates = [AnyObject]()

    init() {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            WCSession.defaultSession().delegate = self
            WCSession.defaultSession().activateSession()
            WatchDataProvider.activated = true;
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WCSessionDelegate                

    public func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
        processIncomingMessage(userInfo)
    }

    public func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String: AnyObject]) {
        processIncomingMessage(applicationContext)
    }

    func processIncomingMessage(dictionary: [String:AnyObject] ) {
        // do something with incoming data<
        notifyDelegates()
    }

    // MARK: - QLWatchDataProviderDelegate     

   public func addDelegate(delegate: AnyObject) {
       if !(delegates as NSArray).containsObject(delegate) {
           delegates.append(delegate)
       }
   }

   public func removeDelegate(delegate: AnyObject) {
       if (delegates as NSArray).containsObject(delegate) {
           delegates.removeAtIndex((delegates as NSArray).indexOfObject(delegate))
       }
   }

   func notifyDelegates()
   {
       for delegate in delegates {
           if delegate.respondsToSelector("watchDataDidUpdate") {
               let validDelegate = delegate as! WatchDataProviderDelegate
               validDelegate.watchDataDidUpdate()
           }
       }
   }    
}


// MARK: - Watch Glance (or any view controller) listening for changes

class GlanceController: WKInterfaceController, WatchDataProviderDelegate {

    // A var in Swift is strong by default
    var dataProvider = WatchDataProvider.sharedInstance()
    // Obj-C would be: @property (nonatomic, string) WatchDataProvider *dataProvider

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        dataProvider.addDelegate(self)
    }

    // WatchDataProviderDelegate
    func watchDataDidUpdate() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // update UI on main thread
        })
    }}
}

class AnyOtherClass: UIViewController, WatchDataProviderDelegate {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        WatchDataProvider.sharedInstance().addDelegate(self)
    }

    // WatchDataProviderDelegate
    func watchDataDidUpdate() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // update UI on main thread
        })
    }}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `addDelegate()` only append `delegate` if it does *not* already exist in the `delegates` array?

Answer (score 3):

Doing the session management (however WCSession is singleton) in a View-Controller smells like MVC violation (and I've seen too many Watch blog posts wrong this way already).

I made an umbrella singleton class over the WCSession, that is first strongly referenced from Watch Extension Delegate to make sure it will load soon and do not get deallocated in the middle of work (e.g. when a View-Controller disappears while transferUserInfo or transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo happens in another watch thread).

Only this class then handles/holds the WCSession and decouples the session data (Model) from all the View-Controller(s) in watch app, exposing data mostly though public static class variables providing at least basic level of thread-safety.

Then this class is used both from complication controller, glance controller and other view controllers. Updates run in the background (or in backgroundFetchHandler), none of the apps (iOS/WatchOS) is required to be in foreground at all (as in case of updateApplicationContext) and the session does not necessarily have to be currently reachable.

I don't say this is ideal solution, but finally it started working once I did it this way. I'd love to hear that this is completely wrong, but since I had lots of issues before going with this approach, I'll stick to it now.

I do not give code example intentionally, as it is pretty long and I don't want anyone to blindly copy-paste it.

Comment: I have seen the complete Apple WWDC2015 session for WatchConnectivity. And I know they recommend to set the communication on a very early state! (AppDelegate). I can follow your recommendation. But the question is how do you forward the "delegate" which occurs in the AppDelegate to all the ViewControllers. A very basic method could be to install a timer in all ViewControllers and periodically read though the public static class variables. But I think there is a better way to trigger a function only if the "-(void)session:" is called to go though the public static class variables in the VCs.

Comment: Maybe this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809226/notify-watchkit-app-of-an-update-without-the-watch-app-requesting-it (if CFNotificationCenter is still working in watchOS 2). Complications use 'pull' approach instead, except for force refreshing (which is questionable as it  an easily exceed daily limit).

Comment: igraczech, can you post code for your strong reference? I have done a similar process with an unbrella singleton WatchSessionManager class invoked in the Watch ExtensionDelegate but the delegate session receive messages are not being triggered on the unbrella class. I am not sure if I am correctly keeping the delegate alive or if it is dealocating prematurely.

Comment: OK, then, see my post above. You could put a breakpoint/log inside deinit {} method to see when does it exactly get deallocated.

Comment: @rocotilos just see the post above starting "Well, this is simplified version..." and NO, I do not post a complete code intentionally. This is about understanging, not about Cmd-C/Cmd-V/Cmd-B/WTF?

Answer (score 0):

I found, with *"try and error"*, a solution. It is working, but I don't know exactly why! If I send a request from the Watch to the IOS app, the delegate of that ViewController of the Watch app gets all the data from the main queue from the IOS app. I added the following code in the `- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context` and the `- (void)willActivate` of all ViewControllers of the Watch app:

**By example 0 ViewController:**

[self packageAndSendMessage:@{@"request":@"Yes",@"counter":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",**0**]}];

**By example 1 ViewController1:**

[self packageAndSendMessage:@{@"request":@"Yes",@"counter":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",**1**]}];

```
/*
     Helper function - accept Dictionary of values to send them to its phone - using sendMessage - including replay from phone
 */
-(void)packageAndSendMessage:(NSDictionary*)request
{
    if(WCSession.isSupported){


        WCSession* session = WCSession.defaultSession;
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];

        if(session.reachable)
        {

            [session sendMessage:request
                    replyHandler:
             ^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull replyMessage) {


                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     NSLog(@".....replyHandler called --- %@",replyMessage);

                     NSDictionary* message = replyMessage;

                     NSString* response = message[@"response"];

                     [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticTypeSuccess];

                     if(response)
                         NSLog(@"WK InterfaceController - (void)packageAndSendMessage = %@", response);
                     else
                         NSLog(@"WK InterfaceController - (void)packageAndSendMessage = %@", response);


                 });
             }

                    errorHandler:^(NSError * __nonnull error) {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            NSLog(@"WK InterfaceController - (void)packageAndSendMessage = %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        });

                    }


             ];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"WK InterfaceController - (void)packageAndSendMessage = %@", @"Session Not reachable");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"WK InterfaceController - (void)packageAndSendMessage = %@", @"Session Not Supported");
    }

}
```