# Send and receive messages from iPhone to Watch from multiple Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, watchconnectivity

What is the proper way to handle communication sent and received from multiple controllers?

What I'm trying to do is send a message from two different viewControllers from iOS to two different interfaceControllers in WatchOS (separately, NOT at the sametime).

Here is what I have which only works for communication between ViewController2 and InterfaceController2, it crashes when a messages is sent from ViewController1 to InterfaceController1 since it appears to be targeting the `session` method from InterfaceController2 all the time.

### ViewController 1:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController,WCSessionDelegate{
    var session: WCSession!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
          session = WCSession.default()
          session.delegate = self
          session.activate()
        }
     }

      func sendDataToWatch(){
        let sendPrice:[String: Double] = ["price": 3.99]
        session.sendMessage(sendPrice, replyHandler: { replyMessage in
            // Some reply here, this could be nil
        }, errorHandler: {error in
            // Catch any errors here, this could be nil
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        })
     }
}
```

### InterfaceController 1: Receives message form ViewController 1

```
class InterfaceController1: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate{
   var session: WCSession!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }

   func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

    /// Capture data from ViewContorller 2
    let priceFromPhone = message["price"] as? String

    // do something with priceFromPhone
   } 
}
```

// ===========================================

### ViewController 2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController,WCSessionDelegate{
    var session: WCSession!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
          session = WCSession.default()
          session.delegate = self
          session.activate()
        }
     }

   func sendDataToWatch(){
    let sendEngine:[String: Double] = ["engine": 2.5]
    session.sendMessage(sendEngine, replyHandler: { replyMessage in
        // Some reply here, this could be nil
    }, errorHandler: {error in
        // Catch any errors here, this could be nil
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    })
  }
}
```

### InterfaceController 2: Receives message from ViewController 2

```
class InterfaceController2: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate{
   var session: WCSession!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }

   func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

      /// Capture data from ViewContorller 2
      let engineFromPhone = message["engine"] as? String

      // do something with engineFromPhone
    }    
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest removing all data management away from the controllers that handle your UI. It is a poor design and will likely cause you headaches later to mix the layers like this.

You should instead have a data manager that is the `WCSession` delegate and takes care of persisting the information, and then notifying the relevant parties (view controllers, etc) that the backing data has been updated.

Comment: @ ccjensen - Thank you for the good suggestion. Quick question. I will be sending information from multiple iOS ViewControllers to multiple InterfaceControllers in WatchOS, do you recommend creating a data model in each device and then use those models as the central communication in each device?

Comment: Yea, that sounds like a sensible approach to me. Then the view controllers on either side will let the user edit data, which gets communicated to the model layer and then maybe have a communication manager that subscribes to model changes and decides what, when and how to communicate the changes to the counterpart

Comment: I will give a try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have read, it looks like I will need to narrow down the communication to only one ViewController and one InterfaceController and then share the changes via `NSNotification` or `Delegation`.

[WatchConnectivity how to share session among multiple WKInterfaceControllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391480/watchconnectivity-how-to-share-session-among-multiple-wkinterfacecontrollers)

[Using WCSession with more than one ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574961/using-wcsession-with-more-than-one-viewcontroller)